# Front end autocomplete popup becomes black

Tags: front-end, autocomplete

I have an annoying problem with Mathematica front end. Sometimes, the autocomplete popup becomes black and the content becomes unreadable as shown in the attached image. This can be fixed by restarting the Mathematica front end, but I don't want to do that every time.

May I know if there is any fix to this issue. Any input are welcomed. ^_^

Thank you in advance!

[image: Black popup]

Comment: does it still happen if you reset mathematica? see http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464

Comment: I have/had the same issue on Linux with Mathematica 11.2. It wasn't something that happened during the pre-release and it was introduced in the final release of 11.2 (which is nice since it pretty much destroys the purpose of having a pre version). I haven't seen it for a while though.

Comment: @halirutan I feel like it's happened to me when I crunch my front end by having massive graphics and the like. Couldn't replicate it if I tried though.

Comment: @Nasser I tried reset Mathematica, but the problem still exists. Most of the time it happens after I disconnect from an external screen. Is there anyway we can reset the graphics so that I can fix it without restarting Mathematica?

Comment: It's happening to me on Mac with Mathematica 11.1